# how to do 2 subrequest to count man and woman in a table

Tags: sql, count, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a problem in a request in SQL:
I have to count number of man women in a school:

here my table :

[image: request]

I would like to got number of man and women from the table : teacher

But problem is that I must got it with using 2 sub request.

I just do it :

```
select count(Sexe) from teacher where teacher.Sexe='M'
```

thanks for reading me!

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`!

Comment: Yes I did group by,  but I must do with 2 subrequest ( order of my teacher)

Comment: "Yes I did group by"  Where???  I don't see it in your query.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to got number of man and women from the table : teacher

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    sum(case when sexe = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) count_m,
    sum(case when sexe = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) count_f
from teacher
```